# Images in dynamic divs not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looping through images and create dynamic divs. But the images are not displayed, though console.log() shows that parameters of ready() function in the loop are valid. It shows myDiv1 and address of the first image in the array and myDiv2 and address of the second image. What's wrong with the code?

Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view_topic.css">
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="outerdiv"></div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
    id: 'myDiv1',
    //innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
    className: 'img-wrapper'
    })
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
    id: 'myDiv2',
    //innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
    className: 'img-wrapper'
    })
    );
});
$(this).css('height',"100px");

var get_a_image = ["http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/20200804_225812.jpg", "http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/8871677_tsumpy_laba_3.docx"];
var counter = 1;
var ready_cnt = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)  {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv' + ready_cnt + 1).append($('<img id="theImg2">').attr({
    'src': get_a_image[ready_cnt] , //'https://' + imgUrl ,
    'alt': 'test image ' + ready_cnt + 1
    })
    ).scrollTop(9999)
    console.log("get_a_image[" + ready_cnt + "]=" + get_a_image[ready_cnt]);
    console.log('#myDiv' + (ready_cnt + 1));
    ready_cnt++;

  });
}
</script>
    
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: _"Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute."_ (Source: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)) - Why is this _in_ a `for` loop?

Comment: What should I do? For loop is maybe a mistake. In my bigger code it is inserted as separate script in <?php while() { ?>

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to get the increased value of `ready_cnt`. If not, it will be regarded to select an ID of `myDiv01`

```
$('#myDiv' + (ready_cnt + 1)).append(...)
```